# Remove Link from Wordpress Menu

Tags: menus

I am looking to remove the `<a>` from around a wordpress link and replace it for a `<span>`.

There are lots of articles about how to remove the `href=""` but this still leaves the `<a>`.

Example output:
You will see on the "About us" there is no `<a>`

```
        <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/work">Our work</a></li>
            <li><span>About us</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#/about/history">History</a></li>
                    <li><span>The team</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#/about/team/management">Management</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/about/team/sales">Sales</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/about/team/development">Development</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Comment: What problem does this solve? What is the PHP code that is generating the output currently?

Comment: I assume you want the parent menu to not link anywhere and only act as a button to open the children? If that's the case, simply use Custom Link and empty out the URL when making the menu. It should output `<a>` without href and it won't link anywhere

Comment: A solution could be custom nav walker. Without that you can't just remove the <a>

Comment: @TomJNowell For mmenu.js parent items cannot be <a>. I know there is a plugin but you are unable to customise the menu through the plugin and trying to integrate it manually.

Comment: @iamonstage I can find no evidence of this on the mmenu.js website, the reason it's using a span is not because it's required, but because the specific example uses a span. On https://mmenujs.com/tutorials/off-canvas/the-menu.html it says _If our website has no main page for the "about" section, we could replace the <a href="/about/" /> with a <span />._ The problem you are trying to solve does not exist.

Comment: Check the `Open submenus` section of https://mmenujs.com/tutorials/off-canvas/the-menu.html, `<li><a href="#/about">About us</a>` works just as well if not better

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell But mmenu is not picking up the submenu and just displaying it as a list?

Comment: Got it fixed, thanks. I had the ID target as the <ul> rather than the wrapping container.